Person column doesn't wrap to multiple lines when multiple persons are added
I have a list displayed on a SharePoint sitepage. In this list, there is a column containing persons or groups. Problem: When multiple persons are added, these are shown as one long string without separator:
 Moreover, when the number of persons gets to long the remaining persons just fall outside the column limit (see purple person 6).
When I go to the list itself (and not the list as displayed/embedded on a SharePoint site), it does wrap nicely underneath eachother: 
How can I style the display of the column embedded on the SharePoint site in such a way it is the same as shown when going to the list itself? So nicely wrapped within column limits underneath each other?

The following JSON code seems to work, found at this question:
How to separate 'Person or Group' column values by a comma and display on one line?
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=join(@currentField.title, ', ')"
}

At least now the text wraps nicely within column borders. Credits to @Ganesh Sanap - MVP
